# Dimension of $\text{Sym}^n(\mathcal{H})$

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetry, kronecker-product

Let $\{A_i\}$ be a set of $d-$dimensional matrices. $A_1\otimes A_2$ refers to the tensor product or Kronecker product of $A_1$ and $A_2$. We now look at symmetric tensor products i.e. linear combinations of terms like $A_i\otimes A_i\otimes...$

I came across a result (just after (5) in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.3019.pdf)) that claims that the space of any linear combination of these i.e.

$$\left\{B: B=\sum_{i} p_{i} A_{i}^{\otimes n}, \quad p_{i} \in \mathbb{R}, A_{i} \in \mathbb{C}^{d \times d}\right\}$$

has a dimension bounded by $(n+1)^{d-1}$. Naively, I would have expected the dimension of $B$ to be $d^n$. How is this result obtained?

Comment: What do you mean by the "dimension" of a matrix?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom apologies if this is wrong terminology but I mean the dimension of the linear space of $B$. I understand that the matrix still has $d^n$ elements. I can edit if this terminology is correct. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you are indeed using terminology incorrectly. To make things as unambiguous as possible: it seems that you are talking about the dimension of the subspace given by $$
\{B:B = \sum_{i}p_i A_i^{\otimes n}, \quad p_i \in \Bbb C, A_i \in \Bbb C^{d \times d}\}.
$$ 
Is my interpretation correct?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom yes, thank you for that. I only had real $p_i$ in mind but I will now edit to correct the terminology.

Comment: Perhaps you should explicitly mention that you're interested in $\text{Sym}^n(\mathcal H)$ (for a finite dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal H$).

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you for your comments and improving my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_tensor) that for a $d^2$-dimensional space $V$, the dimension of $\operatorname{Sym}^n(V)$ is given by 
$$
\binom{n + d^2 - 1}{d^2-1} = \frac1{(d^2 - 1)!} \cdot (n + d^2 - 1)(n+d^2 -2) \cdots (n+1)\\
= \frac{n+d^2-1}{d^2 - 1} \cdot \frac{n+d^2 - 2}{d^2 - 2} \cdots \frac{n+1}{1} \\
\leq (n+1)\cdot (n+1) \cdots (n+1) = (n+1)^{d^2 - 1}.
$$
This is the bound used in the paper.